# Software to map custom keys on a keyboard / mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm searching for a software which can *bind* commands / actions / etc. to the custom keys on my keyboard / mouse.

[image: Keyboard with custom keys]

I mean the keys: Mode, M1-9 & C1-9

[image: Mouse with custom buttons]

I know there is always special software and drivers required, however I thought there may be a tool for me, because those softwares don't run on my computer.

Comment: Don't know what to do for the keyboard but for the mouse, you may want to check out [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm). I use it with [this mouse](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) and it picked up every key on it, hopefully it'll do the same for yours as well.

Comment: The extra keyboard keys may depend on how they're detected first. If they're unusual standard keys, then maybe AHK would do the trick

Comment: This question is asking for multiple pieces of software, if you could please split this question up where one asks for software for the mouse and the other question asks for software for the keyboard. This way we won't have answers containing two pieces of different software, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotkey. It let's you record key presses, and then you can see what the name for that specific key is, and bind to it with an AutoHotkey script.

I used to do this several years back.