# 【switch the value of PrtSc button to Rightmouse buttom】

Tags: windows, software-development, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

【switch the value of PrtSc button to Rightmouse buttom】
Does this button has a certain name? Is there any software that can help me switch PrtSc button on my laptop to the Rightmouse buttom permanently?
[image: no-name button]
[image: PrtSc button]

Comment: Related, or even possible duplicate: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33933/software-to-map-custom-keys-on-a-keyboard-mouse

Comment: that's called the [*menu key* or *application key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)

Answer (score 1):

The key you have highlighted is called the context menu key.

I found a program tutorial of sorts for [mapping any key](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) on a Windows machine. It covers a program called SharpKeys that may be of value for you, as it covers "special" keys that might otherwise not be part of an ordinary layout.